# SoundCloud activityType for ChromeCast

Tags: soundcloud, google-cast

i know there are `YouTube` and `Netflix`, but is there appId for sending SoundCloud tracks to ChromeCast?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this page says that other [DIAL listed apps](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-registry/namespace-database) are valid as well: https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender (under Activity launch)

However, SoundCloud is not listed there. I haven't tried any other DIAL apps either.

Comment: soundcloud is not listed here. never mind, i already got my AppId and started my own sender/receiver apps.

Comment: @cucko my bad, forgot to mention that SoundCloud wasn't there. Good luck with your own app!

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 95% certain the answer to that question is no. If they (Google) haven't advertised specific apps as being available, then there is no App Id for it. At least not one that's publicly available. But, you could write an app to do it.

Comment: i'm planing to create an app, still waiting for my cromecast device to get my appId from google. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Mono for casting SoundCloud and much more..
http://mono-cloud.appspot.com